# Prove that $c^{1/n}$ is decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that $c^{1/n}$ is decreasing if c>1.
Is there any way to prove this easily. I have 
a proof using logarithms. Is there any other proof? (simple proof using properties of real numbers or by *induction*)

Comment: By differentiation? If $n$ is natural, then induction?

Comment: @Shuri2060 that's what I want...prove it by induction..I already tried.but failed

Comment: You forgot to tell decreasing wrt which variable. We have to guess $n$.

Comment: Is $n$ a positive integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{c^{1/(n+1)}}{c^{1/n}} = c^{1/(n+1) - 1/n} < 1,$$
where the inequality holds because $c > 1$ and in the middle expression we are taking $c$ to a negative power. We conclude that $c^{1/(n+1)} < c^{1/n}$, so the sequence is decreasing as claimed.

Answer (score 2):

Let $b=c^{1/n(n+1)}$. Then $b>1$, $c^{1/n}=b^{n+1}$ and $c^{1/(n+1)}=b^n$.
So $c^{1/n}>c^{1/(n+1)}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $m>n$, we have $c^{1/m}<c^{1/n}$ because taking the $mn^{th}$ power we get

$$c^n<c^m, $$ or $$1<c^{m-n}.$$

---

For completeness, $c^p$ is a monotonic function of $p$, and the inequalities are preseved.

Answer (score 0):

Note: $$c>1 \Rightarrow c^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}>1.$$
Then: $$c^{\frac{1}{n}}>\frac{c^{\frac{1}{n}}}{c^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}}=c^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$$
because it is divided by a number greater than $1$.